# [TURBOREPO]: is it possible to use remote-cache pointing to the vercel service instead of making own cache server

Tags: netlify, vercel, monorepo, turborepo

Turborepo labels that
`If you are building and hosting your apps on Vercel, Remote Caching will be automatically set up on your behalf once you use turbo. You need to update your build settings to build with turbo.`

and what if I deploy my stack at netlify, can I still use the caching service that vercel provides?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty sure you can. Don't think it matters where are you deploying it.
You'll still have to do:

```
npx turbo login
```

and

```
npx turbo link
```

in order to access the cache.

You'll then need to link your CI to Vercel Remote cache, it means grabbing TOKEN, API and TEAM from Vercel config and adding them to your `ci.yaml` configuration as a turbo env vars.

See CI Recipes [docs](https://turbo.build/repo/docs/ci) for details.